# Do stash size increments carry to new characters?

Tags: diablo-iii

Just started playing, the 10k to increase my stash size appears very costly right now.

Does that increase then work for all characters on my account or will I need to spend the 10k+ for each character that wishes a larger stash?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The Stash is shared between all of your (non-hardcore) characters. Capacity upgrades are shared as well.

That said, early on stash capacity upgrades are an *extremely* inefficient use of your gold. You're better off making an additional character to act as a mule to hold on to that cool axe you want to give to your barbarian someday - it's slightly inconvenient to move stuff around, but compared to the inconvenience of raising 10,000 gold at this point in the game, it's definitely the better choice.

Comment: You don't need that much space early in the game anyway. Bought the first upgrade during act 2 nightmare and that was mainly so I can sort my gems nicely.

Answer (score 8):

Every account has two stashes that are shared between characters (one Hardcore, one Softcore), so any stash expansion upgrades affect all of your characters of the same type.

Again: Hardcore and softcore have separate stashes, so upgrading a softcore stash will not increase the items available in hardcore.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz I'm not sure that's right. [This page](http://www.diablowiki.net/Stash) seems to say that hardcore characters have a shared stash. Has anyone tested this? (Unfortunately I can't atm)

Comment: @Sterno on it.!

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz So I just checked, and you're wrong. Hardcore Characters share a stash.