# What does the Damage stat on the character sheet actually mean? How is DPS Calculated?

Tags: diablo-iii

[image: Screenshot of the character sheet with the Damage stat and value circled]

The Damage stat on the character sheet is... not very well explained. I have trouble understanding why some items make it go up or down. It says I do 184.52 damage, but my weapon only does 34 DPS and does 8-41 damage per hit.

What is the formula behind this stat? What does it actually represent? Damage per Attack? Damage per Second? Some abstract constant? And what does this have to do with the damage done by my abilities?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

So, the Damage Stat on the character sheet represents an estimate of DPS, but it factors in a number of stats, including some that you don't see clearly elsewhere on the character sheer.

First off, it factors in the bonus to damage from your characters primary Stat. We'll refer to that as **S** from here on out. **S** is a multiplier equal to your Strength, Dexterity, or Intellect as appropriate.

> **S** = 214 (primary attribute)
>
>         × 1% (bonus damage per point)
>
>         + 1 (base)
>
>    = **3.14**

Next, it accounts for your chance to get a critical strike, as well as the magnitude of bonus damage gained from Crits. We'll call this **C**. Because we're accounting for the *average* amount of damage gained from crits, we can just multiply the crit damage by the crit bonus (as percentages) to get the multiplier. My Demon Hunter doesn't have any gear or talents that modify her crit chance or damage, so that makes the math here easy.

> **C** = 5% (chance to crit)
>
>         × 50% (bonus damage on crit)
>
>         + 1
>
>    = **1.025**

Next, it accounts for Weapon Speed. We'll call this **R** for 'Rate of Fire'. This includes any modifiers that increase your Attack Speed, such as the bonus earned for dual wielding, or from having a Quiver equipped in the case of my Demon Hunter, I have a Quiver, and an Amulet that provide a combined 17% bonus to my bows base attack speed of 1.4. Fortunately, we don't have to do any math here. The character sheet flat tells me:

> **R** = **1.64**

Now we come to the big one. Average Damage, which will abbreviate as **A** in our formula. What we want here is the Average Damage done by every single shot. This includes bonuses such as those from the two Rings of Wounding (+2-4 Damage each in my case), and the Amulet of Wounding (+3-6 Damage in my case) that my Demon Hunter is wearing. So we take the base damage range of 8-41, and add on two bonuses of 2-4, and another of 3-6. We can just add all the minimum and maximum numbers together here, to get 15-55. Remember not to include elemental damage bonuses that are on your weapon - these are already included in the weapons damage range as displayed! Average the two to find **A**. Dual Wielders, remember to apply all the appropriate bonuses to *both* weapons -  you'll be averaging four numbers if you have two weapons.

> **A** = (55 + 15) / 2
>
>    = **35**

Finally, you multiply this by any other percentage modifiers that you might have from talents. We can call these **M**. My Demon Hunter doesn't have any of these as I'm set up right now, but *if* I were to use the *Archer* talent, that'd be a 15% bonus, making

> (**M** = **1.15**)

Then we just do some multiplication!

## Damage =  SCRAM

> **3.14 × 1.025 × 1.64 × 35** = 184.74

We can account for the discrepancy because we took the character sheets word for the Weapon Speed stat, rather than calculating out the +17% modifier there ourselves. If, instead of using 1.64, we calculate out the weapon speed ourselves, we get **R** = **1.638**, and then we see our expected result: **184.52**

Now, it's important to note that, among other things, this number *doesn't tell you how hard your abilities will hit*. What it does give you a ballpark for is, if you fire off the same ability constantly, how much damage will you do?

But what if you *do* want to know how hard Evasive Shot will hit? After all, it does *125% of weapon damage*. But *what does that mean?* Well, we can use our existing variables -  we just need to remove C and R from the equation -  C is still helpful for getting an idea of how much damage ten Evasive Shots will do, and R will tell us how fast we can fire them off -  both important if we want to know how much damage we can do spamming Evasive Shot, but to know how hard an individual ability will hit, you can use this formula:

## Ability Damage =  SAME

Where **E** is the percentage modifier applied to your weapon damage by the ability. For Evasive Shot, **E** = **1.25**

So, in the case of my Evasive Shot, I can expect it to hit for an average of **137 Damage**.

So, what's the takeaway from all of this for you? Should you care about maximizing the 'Damage' stat on the character sheet? The short answer is, for most players in most situations, yes. You can rely on the '+ Damage' comparison tooltip to tell you whether something is an upgrade. The primary edge case where you might need to pay close attention to this is if you get a lot of your damage from an ability that you can't or don't use very often -  if you can't spam an ability, **R** becomes much less important to you, and you should take into account that while the character sheet looks at the rate of fire, you might not care about it so much. In these cases, doing the math yourself might tell you that a slightly lower DPS weapon is better - if it hits hard enough to make up for the difference.

Comment: For some reason, if you have one one handed weapon and an off hand, bonus damage like '+1-2 fire damage' on the weapon isn't included in weapon dps or character dps. But, bonus damage from the off hand is.

Comment: but I am just wondering where did u get all this informations at? How did u figure all this out? Can we find this anywhere on the blizzard website?

Comment: @Mrsomeone all the information you need to reverse-engineer the formula is right there in the tooltip in my screenshot at the top of the question. As for the 'base factor' of 1, it's because your primary stat's contribution is added on to damage you'd do with a stat of 0. It's not a straight multiplier because if it were, and I had a Dex of 50, I'd be doing half damage!

Comment: In case of dual wielding, which weapon is taken into account? Do they add each others damage range?

Comment: @Allov both are. You'd add both weapons min and max and *divide by 4* to determine the average damage.

Comment: I was with you up to step calculate A you state "two bonuses of 2-4, and another of 3-6" where did these come from... also 8+2+3 = 13 and 41+4+6 = 51 so how do you arrive at 15-55?

Comment: @Mike In my case, I had two rings, with +2-4 Damage and an Amulet with +3-6 damage equipped. Total of 7-14 additional damage. 7+8= 15, 41+14=55. I've edited the answer to clarify that point.

Comment: Ability damage isn't actually quite as cut and dry. You're neglecting to mention that some skills scale with your attack speed as well (i.e, they scale with the "damage" stat in your inventory screen instead of purely your weapon damage), and it's not immediately obvious which ones do and which ones don't.

Comment: Actually inside a longer span of time, it is, but sometimes having a fast weapon is better (with fast, 1 hit takes enemy to 50%, 2nd kills - with slow, 1 hit takes enemy to 10%, 2nd kills -- fast is better in that situation.)

Faster weapon also lets you push out your abilities faster (less cast delay), at least as a wizard, which is real important for kiting.

Comment: @red do enemies have armor in this game, that reduces every attack by X damage?  That makes a big difference in deciding if you want weak+fast or strong+slow.

Comment: Umm, what? No it doesn't. If you hit the enemy for 500 and he has 50% reduction, two hits will do 500 damage. If you hit it with a slower weapon for 1000, you will still end up dealing 500 damage. If the enemies had FLAT damage reduction, then I suppose you'd be correct, but alas, that is not how resistances and armor work.

Comment: @red: Armor in most games reduces damage by a static amount, not a percentage, which is why I was asking.  However, note that your argument works the other way as well:  it could be that, with slightly higher damage, you get the kill in one less hit, in which case the higher damage is preferable.

Comment: http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/5730074199?page=1#8 hydra is affected by attack speed.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft: Interesting, I've been of the opposite opinion.  For most online games I know, armor is a percentage, with Ryzom being the only exception.