# Damage attribute in character/inventory screen good enough for wizards?

Tags: diablo-iii

Does the damage attribute suffice to understand what the base DPS is for wizards also?
(see which attribute i'm referring to as per screenshot).

I mean, can I base my build and spell damage on that attribute alone?
I see that it changes also with changes to my intelligence, so i'm guessing it's everything I need to know how much damage my magic missile (110%) makes, for instance, in DPS.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You pretty much nailed it. All your Intelligence, +Damage, Crit Chance, and other such stats are rolled up and multiplied out to give you the number pictured. All your ability damage, even as a Wizard, is based on that.

[Here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843) is a related question with a great answer containing details on where that number comes from.

In your example with Magic Missile dealing 110% weapon damage, if you are all-out casting Magic Missile, you can expect to do 110% of pictured 39.03 per second (which would be around 43 DPS with Magic Missile).

There could be other factors, like debuffs on enemies, that further change how much damage you do to those particular enemies.  But the number pictured is your general overall  damage value.

Comment: cool thanks. the primary reason why I am asking, is that I kept reading the details and could not find anywhere a good descriptive damage, when it was in plain sight all along. and after seeing all these formulas around the site and videos, not once did one note that it's that number and stop doing math in your head.