# What is the preferred order of DPS stats for the Monk?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

A little theorycrafting here, **which attributes should a Monk focus on from a pure DPS perspective?**

Obviously in the case of Dexterity there are other effects to consider on the whole, such as the added chance to dodge and the effects that could be provided by passive skills in relations to that, but what about things like...

- Additional Critical hit chance
- Additional Critical hit damage
- +Damage
- +Elemental Damage
- +Attack Speed

Et cetera, Et cetera, basically looking for a hierarchy of skills that should be considered if one is trying to purely increase their damage.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the Damage stat takes all that into account.  Just go with whatever that says.

Comment: I'm not convinced that this question is particularly useful once you understand the answer to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-it-calcul). The short version is: They're all good, take the one that you can get the most of. The only notable exception is if you're concerned about resource conservation (which deprecates attack speed), triggering more on-hit effects such as life leech (which increases it's value), or have a passive skill that triggers on crits.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Since the monk resource is generated by attacking, attack speed is not deprecated by resource costs, with the exception of Seven-Sided Strike, where the resource is a cooldown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the standpoint of your weapon: Weapon Damage is king. Above all else, you want the highest possible amount of raw damage and DPS possible. Beyond that, you'll want to take a look at [this formula](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-it-calcul) to understand the value of other stats.

In short: at low levels, nothing is going to beat raw +Damage on any slot where you can get it (Rings, Neck, Offhand). As you increase in level, you'll eventually reach a point of inflection where the multiplicative scaling gained from adding +Dex is more valuable than the straight + Damage. This point of inflection will vary with other stats, and particularly with the base DPS of your weapon -  your best bet is to simply keep an eye on the +Damage portion of the tooltip when comparing items.

As for stats like Crit and Attack Speed, the same basic rules apply. In general, .1 attack speed is worth 10 Dex, but this ignores the defensive benefits of Dexterity, and since attack speed bonuses are provided as percentage multipliers, you'll need to do some math. You'll need to run similar calculations with +Crit and +Crit Damage, but in general, unless you use skills or passives that rely on Crit, you can assume those stats are less valuable than the others.

Really, all of this comes back to one key point: **Trust the Damage Stat on your Character Sheet**. So long as you're doing the basics right (using a level appropriate, high DPS weapon), it isn't going to steer you far wrong. Beyond that, **Dexterity is King**, and everything else depends entirely on the magnitude of the stat that you get. An item with +Crit might be better than an item with +Attack Speed, based purely on *how much of it is there*.

Comment: Crit may be better than AS, based on how much of *other damage stats* you have.  All else being equal, a change in _any_ single damage stat is a linear change.

Answer (score 0):

The DPS show on the weapon already considers % of dmg and % of attack speed.

You can do that by doing simple math while looking at the item.

But those stats still count for the second weapon, in case you have one. So you should consider that if you wield 2 weapons.

Besides that +dmg and +elemental dmg are hude increasers also, but not as good as attack speed in my opinion.

Depending on your build you should consider trying critical hit chance with critical a high critical demage while using swepping wind with cyclone rune.

Comment: This is incorrect. +Attack Speed and +Damage, when found on weapons, *do not* apply to other weapons when dual wielding.

Comment: I didnt say that. I say that those stats count for the weapon, and they will still count for the other one.

Comment: Except that *they won't count for the other one*. That's my whole point. If I have a weapon with +Damage, *my other weapon does not benefit from that +damage*.

Answer (score 0):

Most important:

- Weapon dps (the number displayed) which is based on:

  - Base damage range
  - Base weapon speed
  - +damage %
  - +damage range with a type
  - +attack speed %
  - +attack speed (decimal)

Important (you should prioritize getting both of these):

- Non-weapon attack speed increases
- Core stat

Critical Hit damage becomes better and better as your Critical Hit chance increases, but should be focused on only when you have little else to improve elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You've been given some obvious answers: things to prioritize are pure DPS on your weapons and dexterity (in that order).

The next priority is absolutely based on your build but I think attack speed should be the next priority since monk is based on spirit and more spirit regeneration due to higher attack speed means more spells which either translates into more damage or more health, again, depending on your build.

High spirit regeneration also works particularly well with gain x life per spirit spent abilities and gear. Let's say you gain 70 life per spirit spent and you have 150 spirit. That's 10500 health regenerated and you can generate a full spirit pool every couple of seconds, making this the best heal our class has. It actually scales with stats you can improve.