# Does the Barbarian's Frenzy speed bonus affect other skills?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-barbarian

Given that increasing your attack speed increases your DPS, do other skills take advantage of this higher DPS?

I thought they did, but I noticed that the speed increase from the
Frenzy skill doesn't affect the *Damage* item shown in the character
menu. So now I'm not sure. If I accumulate 5 Frenzy, and then perform
a different special attack (e.g. *Hammer of the Ancients*), will it
deal more damage than without the Frenzy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attack speed does not increase the damage of your abilities (normally, it may have some effect on cooldown skills), but what it *does* do is decrease the animation times for your abilities. (And for the record, it *should* also increase the Damage stat on the character pane)

And the frenzy stacks *definitely* decrease the animation times.

The underlying problem, I believe, is more generally that the Damage value in the character pane doesn't take into account the fury stacks (I assume because of their brief length), but if you expand the pane to show weapon speed, you will see that you *do* have the increased speed represented there.

Comment: Pretty sure that he's referring to [Damage](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-it-calcul) on the character sheet. Which *very much is* affected by attack speed.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Yes. He asked this question because he didn't note any change in that stat. I'm telling him, even if the stat doesn't change, he's still getting the attack speed (which you can see if you compare your weapons individually with the "More Details" window).

Comment: Ok. So skill damage (in general) takes your *Damage Per Attack* into account, not your *DPS*?

Comment: @BruceConnor yes... but since you can get more attacks with a faster weapon, DPS is still an effective metric. (Again, the animation time decreases)