# Is the + weapon damage% included in the displayed damage?

Tags: diablo-iii

If I have a a weapon that does +10% damage with 10-20 base damage, is the 10% already included in the 10-20 or will really it do 11-22?

How does that work with other damage items, such as rings and off-hand items?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any bonuses or modifiers that are gained from an affix *on the weapon itself* are already factored in to the items stats when you view it's tooltip.

Bonuses to +Damage or Attack speed on *other items*, such as rings and off-hands are **not** reflected in the tooltip of your weapon, but **are** factored in to [the Damage stat on the character sheet.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-it-calcul)

Keep in mind however, that affixes such as + Damage and + Attack Speed, when found *on a weapon*, **do not** affect your other weapon if dual wielding. This includes the benefit of gems like Rubies.

Comment: also may want to mention that the auction house interface does not take into account stats from gems like it does in game

Comment: @Mr.November the Auction House UI is... horribly buggy with respect to DPS from gems. The behavior is just super inconsistent. (The item tooltips are correct, the DPS listing in the search view is not, etc.)

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFixx That usually only applies to gemmed items, and I would call that a feature. I would prefer if you weren't allowed to AH a gemmed item, it artificially raises it in my sort criteria. IE: "chest plate, 1 slot, 100 strength" includes 90-strength CPs with rubies.