# Legendary items that grant a percent based damage increase

Tags: diablo-iii

I recently found the Legendary wand Starfire, which has one of its fixed attributes always roll as 10-15% more damage.

Which other legendary weapons in Diablo 3 have similar %age based boost, and do all of them have the possibility to spawn with a socket? Are there non-weapon legendaries that have a percent-based damage boost?

Comment: This answer should help you: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69724/is-the-weapon-damage-included-in-the-displayed-damage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooltip of the weapon already shows you the corrected dps accounting for the stats (any elemental damage, % based damage, faster attack speed) on the weapon (NB. str/dex/int - for the respective class - is excluded and only shows in the dps value of your character sheet)

Comment: Updated the question, got confused due to legendary status - I've removed the first part about %age damage bonus.