# What does +X% Dmg do in Diablo?

Tags: diablo-iii

I've made a spreadsheet for my barb so I can calculate how much defense and damage I will get from a new item I buy off the auction house and I've got it matching perfectly with the stats shown in the details tab, except for +X% Weapon Damage. 
[image: mace]
I know the extra arcane damage in blue is included in the total damage range in white at the top, is this +34% damage included too? I don't think it is... I used the info in this youtube video to make my spreadsheet

but this doesn't include any +X% Damage.
If you know how the formula works that would be great :)
Cheers

Comment: Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69724/is-the-weapon-damage-included-in-the-displayed-damage

Comment: as per fbueckert, but wow great video!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is included.  You can see the base stats for that item type [here](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/goedendag).  If you subtract off the Arcane Damage your one is 189 - 348.  Dividing by 1.34 puts that at 142 - 259, which is right inside the normal damage range for the base item.  Note that the Bleed damage is not being included in the DPS, so you'd have to account for that yourself.

Answer (score 1):

+x% damage refers to the modifier applied to the base stats for that particular weapon type.

In your example above, it appears that that is a rare [Goedendag](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/goedendag).  The damage for a goedendag has a base minimum of somewhere between 139 and 143, and a maximum between 256 and 264.

The +34% damage modifier is applied directly to those stats, which are randomly determined from within that range.  For this particular weapon, the stats after the +34% bonus give it a range of 189-348 damage per hit.  Then the arcane damage (143-369 in this case) is added on top of that, to determine the weapon's final damage range (332-717).