# Help with item stats!

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the Damage stat on the character sheet actually mean? How is DPS Calculated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-dps-calcu)
>   [How is the weapon damage on this weapon calculated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/75955/how-is-the-weapon-damage-on-this-weapon-calculated)
>   [Is the + weapon damage% included in the displayed damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/69724/is-the-weapon-damage-included-in-the-displayed-damage)

Why does my damage gets reduced when I equip a 969.4 DPS weapon instead of a 698.0 DPS weapon? I'm a wizard.

Weapon A - 698.0 DPS , 605-791 Damage , 1.00 Attacks per second, 93 strength , 371 intelligence.

Weapon B - 969.4 DPS , 961-1192 Damage , 0.90 Attacks per second , Critical hit damage increased by 82% and +33% damage

Assuming that I have no other equipments on except my weapon , why does my damage drop?

Comment: No. He's asking how to calculate Damage and I'm asking about my weapon DPS.

Comment: This is actually a duplicate of multiple questions. I've edited another one into your question which is more specific to your problem than the other question.

Comment: But mine is about STATS like int/str while the others are about minimum/maximum damage and weapon damage %

Comment: @Vorde Read the other questions and their answers. Everything you are asking is answered in them.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't really see it... Where's the link?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have no other equipment on, the difference is done by that 371 intelligence bonus, which is 371% of extra damage.

Comment: To expand on what Novarg said, you probably have relatively low intelligence already and low crit chance on your gear.  If you had more int/crit chance on your other gear, you might see the second weapon doing more dps.

Comment: But the second weapon has higher DPS than the first weapon I thought?

Comment: 698*3.71 > 969 + (some small amount of crit)

Comment: @Vorde to clarify a bit further, the weapon DPS is a simple calculation of attacks/second * average damage of the weapon. Your *actual* dps (what you see on your character sheet after you've equipped the weapon) includes other factors, such as the amount of extra damage Int adds, or how often and how hard you crit.

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: The displayed dps value is already a culmination of all other values. So the display of 698 vs 969 already states, which weapon will deal more damage.

Comment: Althought the DPS on the two different weapons are 969.4 and 698.0 respectively, it doesn't mean that the damage displayed is 969.4 or 698.0 respectively.