# How can I predict how much DPS increase a weapon has on my character?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does the Damage stat on the character sheet actually mean? How is it Calculated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-it-calcul)

Often it is not possible to compare two weapons like in the inventory. Take the AH or some random WTS offer when using another char.

How can I predict / calculate how much DPS my char will deal afterwards, given I have access to all numbers required?

Comment: This question has already been answered on the site. [Click Here](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-it-calcul)To link to the page.
Just a matter of pluggin and chuggin. A spreadsheet would help a lot for this, unfortunately I haven't seen any, and being a tank monk, I'm not super worried about my dps.

Comment: @Dave, if you think you've found a duplicate, hit the "flag" link, which will alert us to the question so that we can handle it.