# Why does +damage items give much greater DPS than damage given by a primary stat?

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is Primary Stat Worth More Than Weapon Damage?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67817/is-primary-stat-worth-more-than-weapon-damage)
>   [What does the Damage stat on the character sheet actually mean? How is it Calculated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-it-calcul)

Let's say I have a ring that has +2-4 damage and another that has +15 dexterity. I am a demon hunter. I find that equiping the +damage ring gives a *much* greater boost to my DPS (as shown on my character screen) than the dexterity ring, which is supposed to increase my damage by 15.

Does anyone know how this works? Does this have anything to do with how +damage is calculated?

Comment: You'll find the information about that in the question [What does the Damage stat on the character sheet actually mean? How is it Calculated?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/67843/what-does-the-damage-stat-on-the-character-sheet-actually-mean-how-is-it-calcul). In short, the +damage bonus modifies your base damage, the 15 dexterity give you only 15% bonus at the end of the calculation.

Comment: Yep, I guess this one didn't come up in the suggestions. Please close. Nice answer by the way.