# What is the exact formula for calculating total vitality? Please include charlevel and paragon level

Tags: diablo-iii

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How are attributes allocated?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66734/how-are-attributes-allocated)

The best answer that I can find is lacking a few specifics: [Percentage life vs vitality?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/70770/percentage-life-vs-vitality)

Given I'm concerned only with total vitality, rather than the tradeoffs %Life and Vit, I've opened a new question. Namely, is a constant in the previous question that is not explained, that I assume are a function of character level. The previous page does also not account for paragon levels.

For reference, the answered formula should use the following parameters to give a total vitality of `1218`. `1023` Vit from gear, level `34` paragon, level `60` barbarian, `10` % Life increase.  Using the referenced formula I've added a term for 2 vit per level of paragon.

```
Total Vit = (127 + GearVitality + 2 * ParagonLvl)
```

Comment: If an existing question/answer does not provide enough detail, request more information there.  Do not ask a new question.

Comment: This isn't a new question. It's a question that relates to another question. By your logic, any question about calculating hit points, effective health, or vitality would need to be under the same original question.

Futhermore the duplicate this is marked as DOES NOT answer this question.  2 Vit per level does not add up to the 127 constant I mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You gain 2 vitality for every level up, including paragon levels.  So the formula you have listed in the question is essentially correct, except that it is 7 + (Level * 2) + (ParagonLevel * 2) + GearVitality.

Comment: Do you know where the 7 constant came from?

Comment: @Tor Your starting Vitality at Level 1 is 9.  That's just the way it is designed.